# Bootstrap 4 Grid format

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

Does anyone know how to do this type of grid style in bootstrap 4?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Its not bootstrap but may be something similar to what you are looking for https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_mediaqueries_img_gallery

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap can't provide that gird system. which you currently want. 
create custom gird system for that , sharing one example with you

[Click here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_mediaqueries_img_gallery)

Comment: i have given you an upvote but i have a question what do you mean by CUSTOM  css or CUSTOM grid system what does custom relative to css mean

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap provides a way to span rows in columns but it does not provide a way to span columns in rows that is to say you cannot span a column on multiple rows  . Its not possible in grid system. you have to use custom html and css for it .

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-4">1</div>
        <div class="col-xl-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-8">2</div>
                <div class="col-xl-4">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-4">4</div>
                <div class="col-xl-8">5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```